# How do I get scripts to run prior to and after sending mail with msmtp?

Tags: msmtp

I would like to use [msmtp](http://msmtp.sourceforge.net) to send mail on my Linux machine. Before and after sending mail using this tool, I would like to execute some scripts to do some setup and teardown.

I don't see an msmtp configuration option to run scripts before and after sending mail. I don't want to "hack" the system by replacing the binary with a script that will do the work. Do I have another option to do this?

Comment: Eh, in a way, you are already "hacking" the system by replacing `/usr/sbin/sendmail` (traditionally a full MTA with queueing and so on) with something like msmtp...

Comment: @grawity: Why? `sendmail` and `msmtp` can live together on the same system, they are 2 separate binaries. Maybe you think about `postfix`.

Comment: I do not have sendmail installed. This question is about how to use msmtp, not whether I have a traditional MTA installed.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately a hack is the only option you have - Linux is not watching and reacting to each and every binary you call so that it can insert pre- and post-action hooks.

Best approach would be to write a custom function and put it into your `.bashrc`.